# Tensorflow error could not load dynamic library on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
2020-08-11 16:57:25.492855: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-08-11 16:57:25.503890: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

I get this error each time I run a program on Python with Tensorflow. I just want to know how to exclude this message. I've tried some things but it remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is simply to silence this warning, put this as the first lines of your code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: Thanks! It's better now :)